# Is linear regression the best method for getting the relationship among 3 variables?

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, random-forest, lasso

I have two independent variables, let's call them $x_1$ and $x_2$, and one dependent variable, $y$.

I don't have some exogenous shock or some natural experiment to capture the causality among theses variables, so I'm appealing to some sort of regression (which I guess is better than just Pearson coefficient).

Is multiple linear regression the best approach to get how much $x_1$ and $x_2$ affects $y$?

Does lasso regression, ridge, or even random forest be better here?

Comment: My hunch would be to use plain vanilla OLS here (assuming its assumptions are met). I am not too familiar with the other techniques mentioned but they seem like overkill.

Comment: Agree with @horseoftheyear. Lasso and ridge don't really make sense with only two independent variables since you are unlikely to over-fit (unless you have *very* little data). In theory, a decision tree could be helpful if $y$'s dependence on the $x_i$ is really threshold based but then you want control for over-fitting. For OLS, maybe consider an interaction term between $x_1$ and $x_2$.You can get a sense of what models would be best by creating a heatmap of $y$ for different values of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OLS here.  It might also depend on your use case.  If you're just explaining the relationship to a colleague, you might use vanilla OLS. If the emphasis is on more accurate predictions, perhaps consider using random forest regression.